# Disk I/O statistics / Measuring disk read activity: How to verify read activity on Disk IO

Tags: caching, filesystems, embedded-linux

I want to read data from disc I/O, not filesystem cache.

A file is stored in disc (dev/sdb, and a thread or process tries to read data from it.
 fd = open("", O_RDONLY); byte = read(fd,...);

If I drop caches before calling the read() function, then get the disc I/O statistic by using the iostat command, then I observed the amount of reads updated.
 system("iostat"); sync(); system("echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches); system("iostat");

But drop_caches is more expensive; I don't want to use it this way.
Others, I am trying to use fsync() before calling read() functions, and then the iostat command rarely reports the amount of reads. I am not sure using fsync() will work as expected.

Could anyone suggest any ideas to verify the read activity with fsync() or suggest other ways how to ensure reading data from disc, not filesystem cache?

Thank you

I want to read data from disc I/O, not filesystem cache.